# How to change the attribute using a new method

Tags: java

Could someone give me any advice to write the following statement correctly because it appears an error?
The code is:

```
    public class Person{
        private boolean old;


        public Person() throws Exception{       
            old = true;
    }
public boolean isOld() {
            return old;
    }       
private void setOld(boolean old) {
        this.old= old;
    }
public boolean turnOld(boolean old) {
        if (isOld(old)= true) {
            setOld(old)=false;
        }
        else {
            setOld(old)= true;
        }

        this.old= old;
        return old;
    }
}
```

The error appears in the method turnOld, more precisely in the setOld and isOld, and it says "The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable"
Can someone help me?

Comment: Use `if (isOld(old) == true)` instead of `if (isOld(old) = true)`

Comment: Use `if (isOld(old))` instead of `if (isOld(old) == true)` and you won't have the potential to make this sort of mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compilation error message is self explanatory :

> "The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable"

Here :

```
setOld(old)=false;
```

`setOld(...)` returns void. You cannot assign any values to that.
You assign values to a variable.
Besides this :

```
isOld(old)= true
```

also cannot compile as `isOld()` doesn't take any parameter and makes no sense as you want to assign `true` to `old` while you make the same mistake as for `setOld()` : you assign a value to something that is not a variable.

What you want seems to be a toggle method for the boolean `old` field, so you could write :

```
public boolean toggleOld() {
    if (isOld() {
        setOld(false);
    }
    else {
        setOld(true);
    }
    return old;        
}
```

Or more simply :

```
public boolean toggleOld() {
    setOld(!isOld());
    return old;        
}
```